Psexec command, not working under powershell 7
A script using psexec no longer works under PowerShell 7, whereas it does under PowerShell 5. To automate tasks, I've created a form that lets you enter commands to be sent with psexec to remote machines in a textbox. I separate the strings with a # to split the command more easily:
Example :
Command in textbox :
powershell#"Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem | Select LastBootUpTime"

Script :
$commandes = $script:CommandesText.Split("#")
$Query = PsExec.exe -nobanner -accepteula -s \\$SelectedServerIP -u admin@$SelectedDomain -p $passwordBox.Text $commandes
Write-Host $Query

PowerShell 7 output, we find the command :
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem | Select LastBootUpTime

PowerShell 5 output, the expected result :
 LastBootUpTime      --------------      14/12/2024 19:56:12

I tried to transform the string into an array but the result is the same:
$commandes = @()
$string_commandes = $script:CommandesText.Split("#")
foreach ($string in $string_commandes) {
    $commandes += $string
}

Thanks

remote powershell?
